# Differentiating with unique id overlapping/intersecting or isolated convex_hulls in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, clustering, geometry-generator, convex-hull

From a layer of 2000 points, I have a field with the name 'NUCLEUS' with four categories (1, 2, 3, 4) that identifies each point with a category of density clusters. In red color you can see the groups of points with category is 1 and that are the points that have the smallest distances between them.

[image]

I have developed the following expression for Geometry Generator to try to represent the nearest neighbours main polygon clusters (using convex_hull geometry object) from the data I have available in the attribute table ("NUCLEUS" field):

```
if( "NUCLEUS" = 1

and

    distance (
        $geometry, 
        collect_geometries (
            overlay_nearest (
                @layer, 
                $geometry 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) < 350 , 

    convex_hull( 
     collect_geometries (
        overlay_nearest (
            @layer,
            $geometry,
            limit:=35
        )
    )
),
    NULL
)
```

[image]

The field 'NUCLEUS' would be equivalent to for example the field 'CLUSTER_ID'. As you can see, by applying the expression I manage to represent the nearest neighbours with the polygonal figure convex_hull.

The problem with this visualitzation is that it is not a unique identifier for each cluster, and therefore what I get is 70 overlapping/intersecting or isolated convex_hulls (one convex_hull per point with category = 1).

The solution I would need, for example, is to be able to differentiate with unique identifier each group of overlapping/intersecting or isolated convex_hulls, so that I could simplify the visualization and go from 70 convex_hulls to 10 as shown in the following screenshot and label the number of points within each 10 convex_hull:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just merge all convex hulls and dissolve them into singlepart features?

Comment: It could be a solution, but the _Geometry by Expression_ algorithm does not work in this case. When I run the expression I get the error message: _Evaluation error: Layer could not be loaded. Execution failed after 0.05 seconds_. Maybe the expression is too complex. On the other hand, my priority is to try to avoid the generation of new intermediate layers, and try to solve the problem in real time with Geometry Generator

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't want to use the convex hull processing tools, QGIS or SAGA?

Comment: In the case of the QGIS core geoalgorithm, there seems to be no possibility to execute an expression. For this reason I have discarded it. In the case of GRASS there is the possibility of parameterizing an output and it is possible to execute a SQL statement for it, but I do not know if it is feasible to achieve what I intend with SQL. And with SAGA I do not know the functionalities of its geoalgorithm to process convex_hull and I don't have any experience in having tested it

Comment: Rather than merging then dissolve you may try to only merge (combine or convex_hull) intersecting convex hull (I think it's the "to singlepart " that made suggestion from @Radde1683 not working but I may be wrong on that)

Comment: I understand, but I think the QGIS core tools/geoalgorithms have no possibility to run under expressions, except for 'Geometry by Expression'. How do you suggest I could execute my expression with QGIS core tools?

Comment: @IngridIngravida "Layer could not be loaded" error message with Geometry by Expression might has to do with the fact that this runs a bit different from Geometry Generator. You can't use e.g. `@layer` variable, but you have to use the actual layer's name: `polygon_layer`. Also aggregate functions work a bit differently, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To "cluster" several polygons that (partially) overlap into one contiguous polygon with Geometry Generator, first collect all polygons, then buffer them with 0. As this would produce the same result for each feature again and again, just run it once for one of the features.

*Above (red): initial polygons with overlaps; below (blue) one multipart polygon, created with Geometry Generator:*
[image]

Use this expression, where you can replace `$geometry` with the expression you use to create the single polygons:

```
case 
when $id = maximum ($id)
then buffer (collect ($geometry), 0)
end
```

**Access each geometry part separately**

This creates one multipart geometry/style. If you want to get the different parts *individually* (e.g. show just one of the clusters), you can convert the geometry parts to a geometry array with [`geometries_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometries-to-array) and use [`index operator []`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-index) (0 for 1st element) to get one of these geometries:

```
geometries_to_array( 
    case 
    when $id = maximum ($id)
    then buffer (collect ($geometry), 0)
    end
)[2]
```

[image]

This can be helpful if you intend to use each cluster part separately for furter geoprocessing, e.g. creating the centroid for each cluster. To do so, use this expression with `array_foreach()` to loop through the geometry array:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        geometries_to_array( 
            case 
            when $id = maximum ($id)
            then buffer (collect ($geometry), 0)
            end
        ),
        centroid (@element)
    )
)
```

*Blue point: centroid for the multipart geomtry (centroid of all 3 blue clusters together); red points: centroid for each cluster individually:*
[image]

You can now use this centroid to style it as a font marker and for the character use Data Driven override with the variable `@geomtry_part_num`

[image]

**Labeling**

Labeling the individual buffers with the number of the points is a bit tricky and needs some workarounds as labeling works on a per-feature basis. You can use Rule based labels and than create a separate label rule for each cluster manually. Use the following expression to create the label and change the array index (here: `[0]`) for each rule to include the other clusters:

```
sum(
    within(
        $geometry,
        geometries_to_array( 
            buffer (
                collect (
                    buffer ($geometry, 2000)
                ), 
                0
            )
        )[0]
    )
)
```

To place the label, use Geometry Generator label placement to create the centroids of each cluster (as above):

[image]

---

**Creating actual Geometries**

By the way: if you want to create actual geometries from this with Geometry by Expression, you must modify the expression as in this context, the aggregate functions `collect()` and `maximum()` do not work an neither does the variable `@layer` that refers to the current layer. You have to use the very layer name (in my case: `buffer`) and the generic `aggregate()` function instead with the aggregate type inserted as argument like this:

```
case 
when $id = aggregate ('buffer','max',$id)
then buffer (aggregate( 'buffer','collect',$geometry), 0)
end
```

This returns the same number of features as the input layer, but only one feature with a geometry. You can use [`Remove null geometries`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisremovenullgeometries) to get rid of these. Run [`Multipart to single parts`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts) if you want to have a separate feature for each cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining all the details of your solution and for going far beyond the initial requirements and offering more possibilities. One last question: could you publish the label expression that adds the total count of points within each buffer?

Comment: See edited answer, **Labeling** part.